# How to Delete Entity from Database and Store a Clone in a Different Database Table in Java/Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My goal is

1. Delete entity in current table
2. Clone the deleted entity to another table to store for future reference

Thanks

Comment: Are you need examples or explanations?

Comment: Little bit of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to not delete first, but rather copy the entity into the table you wish, make sure it is successfull by checking the result code, then delete the entity from the table.

```
INSERT INTO copy_table 
SELECT * FROM original_table
WHERE condition; 

DELETE FROM original_table
WHERE condition;
```

In JPA

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

```
Entity x = jpaRepository.findById(id);

cloneTableJpaRepo.save(x);

jpaRepository.delete(x);
```

Comment: Thanks Susan. I appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help @abe :)